# Progressive matrix with blue squares on either side of a line

Tags: pattern, progressive-matrix

This is another puzzle that no-one seems to have cracked on [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/ravensmatrices/comments/17rqywb/too_difficult_for_me/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=ios_app&utm_name=ioscss&utm_content=1&utm_term=1). It is a Raven's Matrix question from an IQ test, I presume. Does anyone here know the solution?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the answer is

> **OPTION C**

Reason

> The puzzle is to be viewed as the matrix generating 6 numerical outputs associated with each of the halves of the leftmost (or right most depending on how you want to look  at it) tile. To get the number output for a half, one needs to add up the number of blue squares in all the ‘opposing’ halves starting from and including that half thinking row-wise:

> [image]

> You can see that this then, top down speaking, makes a nice number sequence with an obvious pattern: 6,7,8,9.

> To continue the pattern we need something that has 6 squares on top and 3 on the bottom to make 10 and 11…

> Option C is the only one that can fulfill this role and so is the answer.

> [image]

Comment: Nice answer! But I would like to  see some alternatives!

Comment: If anyone finds a better answer I will be highly surprised. I don’t think this pattern existing in the matrix is purely coincidental…